# R: Summing subset of rows based on the value of current row and adding to a new column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with year, country code, and a piece of data. I want to create a new column that sums up the data for the ten year preceding each year-country case, so, e.g., in 1985 in UK, I get a sum of all the data for the UK in 1975-1984.

I ended up using a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(pol4$change)) {
  pol4$change10[i]<-sum(pol4$change[pol4$ccode==pol4$ccode[i] & 
                       pol4$year %in% pol4$year[i]-(1:10)])
 }
```

But I can't help but feel there's a more elegant way of doing this. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Here's an example dataset:

```
set.seed(24)   
pol4<-data.frame(ccode=rep(1:10,each=100),year=rep(1900:1999,times=10), 
            change=sample(1:10,replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your loop; the resulting `change10` column doesn't look like it's supposed to (it's just repeating the sequence 597 followed by 9 times 600).

Comment: @DominicComtois If I am not mistaken, there should be another parentheses i.e. `pol4$year %in% (pol4$year[i]-(1:10))`

Comment: Hmmm different but still odd results I get

Comment: I get for the 1st 6 rows, `0, 3, 6, 14, 20` and after some time, it is all `60`, but I think it is based on the logical index here.

Comment: Yeah it's because the same data `sample(1:10,replace=TRUE)` are recycled over and over. A way to avoid this would be to add the argument `size=1000` to the call to `sample`.

Comment: Yeah, I just threw together a quick reproducible dataset. The actual data set has non-random data for "change" (with most rows actually having zeros...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
pol4 %>% 
  group_by(ccode) %>% 
  mutate(change10 = roll_sum(change, 11, fill=NA, align ="right")-change) %>% 
  head(15)

   ccode year change change10
1      1 1900      3       NA
2      1 1901      3       NA
3      1 1902      8       NA
4      1 1903      6       NA
5      1 1904      7       NA
6      1 1905     10       NA
7      1 1906      3       NA
8      1 1907      8       NA
9      1 1908      9       NA
10     1 1909      3       NA
11     1 1910      3       60
12     1 1911      3       60
13     1 1912      8       60
14     1 1913      6       60
15     1 1914      7       60
```

Comment: Neat! Although I get this when trying on my end: `Error in roll_sum( [...]  : 
  unused arguments (fill = NA, align = "right")`  (RcppRoll v. 0.1.0)

Comment: @DominicComtois version info says `RcppRoll_0.2.1`, but I don't remember installing it from github. Maybe `drat` did:)

Comment: Did the devtools `install_github("kevinushey/RcppRoll")` and works like a charm (0.2.1 as well). Very nice!

Comment: Very neat indeed. Only that I need it to show the partial sum if there are less than ten preceding years (which is the case in many of the more interesting cases I'm looking at). Any way to do that? I should look at the function and see, I guess...

Oh, yeah, I see there's a "partial" setting there. Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, wait, the help file says partial is not yet implemented. Damn. Any way around this?

Comment: @doviod workaround is maybe remove `fill=NA` and append 10 zeros `roll_sum(c(rep(0, 10), change), 11, partial=TRUE, align ="right")`