# Calculate running average in R using first 50 rows

Tags: r

I want to calculate running average of 6th column of my data with a window of 50 and store the averages in the 7th column(Volume) starting from row 50(first 49 rows would be blank or NA)
So far i have referred the below code which stores the values in the first row of 7th column(Volume). How can i change this to start from row 50?

```
for(i in 1: length(StockData[ , 6]-49)) 
{  
  StockData$Volume [i] <- mean(StockData[i:min(i+49, nrow(StockData)),6]) 
}
```

Comment: I need to find it using a for loop only

Comment: It isn't working. The average of first 50 rows should be stored in 50th row of 7th column(volume), average of 2nd to 51st rows in 51 st column and so on

Comment: I am new to R and this code is a bit confusing for me. I want to calculate The average of first 50 rows which should be stored in 50th row of 7th column(volume), average of 2nd to 51st rows in 51 st column and so on using the for loop only

Comment: I posted a modified solution that seems to work for the case you are after

Comment: The code keeps calculating average of last 50 rows only

Comment: I showed an example in the solution I posted with the same values I am getting from `rollmean`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Summing subset of rows based on the value of current row and adding to a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190336/r-summing-subset-of-rows-based-on-the-value-of-current-row-and-adding-to-a-new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we have the index to loop from the 1st to the 49 rows before the last row(`i1`), assign the `mean` to the 'Volume' column by adding each of the index in `for` loop with 49 i.e. `1 + 49 = 50` `2 + 49 = 51` etc.

```
i1 <- 1:(nrow(StockData) - 49)
for(i in i1) StockData$Volume[i + 49] <- mean(StockData[[6]][i:(i+ 49)])
StockData$Volume
#  [1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
#  [8]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [15]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [22]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [29]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [36]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [43]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [50] -0.19629964 -0.24644362 -0.23783891 -0.26612198 -0.24675588 -0.22167644 -0.19686068
# [57] -0.17468898 -0.22060983 -0.24581253 -0.28938032 -0.25877811 -0.23004419 -0.21873832
# [64] -0.25380578 -0.29241801 -0.27468023 -0.26958748 -0.23289877 -0.20673662 -0.19514563
# [71] -0.20304788 -0.25285171 -0.27237608 -0.28292086 -0.27282226 -0.28069595 -0.26402249
# [78] -0.24157390 -0.20787905 -0.18768505 -0.20224311 -0.20345300 -0.19355069 -0.19980993
# [85] -0.21982236 -0.21592697 -0.19056489 -0.18937285 -0.25814298 -0.24351155 -0.22539465
# [92] -0.18168959 -0.20872355 -0.19644329 -0.17326079 -0.13079761 -0.08915261 -0.10408647
# [99] -0.07350988 -0.01842930
```

---

It would be the same values if we use `rollmean` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
rollmean(StockData[[6]], k = 50, fill = NA, align = "right")
# [1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
#  [8]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [15]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [22]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [29]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [36]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [43]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
# [50] -0.19629964 -0.24644362 -0.23783891 -0.26612198 -0.24675588 -0.22167644 -0.19686068
# [57] -0.17468898 -0.22060983 -0.24581253 -0.28938032 -0.25877811 -0.23004419 -0.21873832
# [64] -0.25380578 -0.29241801 -0.27468023 -0.26958748 -0.23289877 -0.20673662 -0.19514563
# [71] -0.20304788 -0.25285171 -0.27237608 -0.28292086 -0.27282226 -0.28069595 -0.26402249
# [78] -0.24157390 -0.20787905 -0.18768505 -0.20224311 -0.20345300 -0.19355069 -0.19980993
# [85] -0.21982236 -0.21592697 -0.19056489 -0.18937285 -0.25814298 -0.24351155 -0.22539465
# [92] -0.18168959 -0.20872355 -0.19644329 -0.17326079 -0.13079761 -0.08915261 -0.10408647
# [99] -0.07350988 -0.01842930
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
StockData <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100 * 7), ncol =7, nrow = 100, 
    dimnames = list(NULL, c(paste0("V", 1:6), "Volume"))))
StockData$Volume <- NA
```